# Fun with fixity

Tags: haskell

OK, so here's a stupid question. I've defined a new `#` operator, and I'm trying to figure out what the hell the fixity declaration should be.

1. I want `#` to be applied *after* `++`. So does that mean the precedence should be *higher* or *lower* than `++`? (`++` is precedence 5.)
2. The type is `(#) :: Foo -> Bar -> Foo`. Do I want left-associative or right-associative? Because it appears to me that one of those will make `x # y # z` type-check, and the other won't.

I know this might seem trivial, but I always *always* seem to get this wrong...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. `$` has the lowest precedence (0) and `$` is always applied "last" so you want `#` to have lower precedence than `++`. Also, you can compare the precedence of `*` and `+`.
2. Left associativity means that `x # y # z = (x # y) # z` (this is how a left fold operates as well). `x # (y # z)` would not type check but `(x # y) # z` would, so you want it to be *left* associative.

Comment: Good point about `+` and `*`. Oh, and I always get folds the wrong way around as well! I wish they'd name them "strict fold" and "lazy fold" or something...

Comment: @ MathematicalOrchid, The way I usually remember it is that `foldr` is right associative, which I associate with 'non-strictness'. Then `foldl` is a more strict version, with `foldl'` being the truly strict variant of the latter.